Nicematrix changes cases and array environment to require \cr or \\ before closing environment
I started receiving errors when I use the cases and array environments and have the [renew-dots,renew-matrix] option enabled for nicematrix. The code below used to compile without error. I found a workaround, but it doesn't seem ideal. (One adds \\ just before closing the environment.):
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\RequirePackage[renew-dots,renew-matrix]{nicematrix}
% \RequirePackage{nicematrix}                    % <--- This works fine.
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 1pt}

\begin{document}

Example 1

\[
    \Phi'(z,T,\mu)=
    \begin{cases}
        0                     & z\notin NS(E), \\
        \Phi_\phi(\delta,\mu) & z
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 1 \\
            0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
        =N\delta                % <--- If one adds \\ here, then this works.
    \end{cases}
\]

Example 2

\[
    \left(
    \begin{array}{c|c}
            \begin{matrix}
                \alpha^{1/2} & \phantom{-}1 \\
                \alpha^{1/2} & -1
            \end{matrix}
             &
            \begin{matrix}
                 & 0 & 0 \\
                 & 0 & 0
            \end{matrix}
            \\ \hline
            \begin{matrix}
                0 & 0 \\
                0 & 0
            \end{matrix}
             & \frac{1}{2\alpha^{1/2}}
            \begin{pmatrix}
                1 & \alpha^{1/2}  \\
                1 & \alpha^{-1/2}
            \end{pmatrix}                % <--- If one adds \\ here, then this works.
        \end{array}
    \right)
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & \phantom{-} 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \phantom{-} 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & \phantom{-} 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & -1            & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}

These are the errors:
Latex Error: ./test.tex:21 Extra }, or forgotten $.

\endarray ->\tbl_crcr:n {endarray}\egroup

\UseTaggingSocket {tbl/finalize}\t...

l.21 \end{cases}

Latex Error: ./test.tex:21 Extra }, or forgotten $.

\endarray ...tbl_restore_outer_cell_data: \egroup

\@arrayright \gdef \@pream...

l.21 \end{cases}

Latex Error: ./test.tex:21 Extra \right.

\endcases ->\endarray \right .

and
Latex Error: ./test.tex:48 Extra }, or forgotten $.

\endarray ->\tbl_crcr:n {endarray}\egroup

\UseTaggingSocket {tbl/finalize}\t...

l.48 \end{array}

Latex Error: ./test.tex:48 Extra }, or forgotten $.

\endarray ...tbl_restore_outer_cell_data: \egroup

\@arrayright \gdef \@pream...

l.48 \end{array}

Latex Error: ./test.tex:48 Missing $ inserted.

Am I doing something wrong?
I'm using the version of nicematrix from May 29, 2024.

Sorry about that, I assume you are using the
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01>

LaTeX release. A patch level 1 bug fix went to CTAN this morning, so should be distributed by texlive and miktex in the next day or so.
Until then you can put this in the preamble:

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \tbl_crcr:n #1 {
     \int_compare:nNnT \g__tbl_col_int > 0
         {
           \tbl_count_missing_cells:n {#1}
         }
     \crcr
   }
\ExplSyntaxOff


Yes, you're right. I'm using LaTeX2e <2024-06-01>. The code you added works for me. I'll watch for the update. Thanks!
